# To count and display the available strings inside an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api called `teachers` like this:

**teachers:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "01",
    "teacherName": "Binky Alderwick",
    "studentIds": [
      "010",
      "024",
      "031"
    ],
    "totalStudents":"20"
  },
  {
    "id": "02",
    "teacherName": "Basilio Gregg",
    "studentIds": [
      "041",
      "075"
    ],
     "totalStudents":"10"
  },
  {
    "id": "03",
    "teacherName": "Binky Alderwick",
    "studentIds": [
      "075",
      "048",
      "035"
    ],
     "totalStudents":"40"
  }
]
```

In the students `JSON`. The property `studentIds` as multiple `strings` inside its `array`.

How can i count those strings and  compare with the property `totalStudents` and display the available students like this:

[image]

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-cgasnc?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your html

```
<h4>Teachers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{teacher.teacherName }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of Students</td>
        <td>{{ teacher.studentIds.length }}</td>
    </tr>   
    <hr>
</div>
```

if you want that format in the updated question, you can use below

```
   <h4>Teachers</h4>
    <div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>{{teacher.teacherName }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number of Students</td>
            <td>{{ teacher.studentIds.length }}/{{teacher.totalStudents}} </td>
        </tr>   
        <hr>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Empty_Soul, Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display Student count you could use this in your template:

```
{{teacher.studentIds.length}}/{{teachers.totalStudents}}
```

Remember that you can access to data via data-binding and therefore display any kind of data that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of items in an array like this:

```
<h4>Teachers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{teacher.teacherName }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of Students</td>
        <td>{{teacher.studentIds.length}}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>   
    <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through teacher list and you can add a property 'availableStudents' as string and you can set it like below and use it wherever you want

```
for(let teacher of teacherList)
{
 teacher.availableStudents=`${teacher.studentIds.length}/{teacher.totalStudents}`}
}
```

And then you are free to use it in HTML.

It is better to add this code in a function name like `computeAvailableStudent` (For better code readabilty) and then after getting list from server, call this function so your list will be ready to use

Its better to compute such things it ts file instead of html so it will be better to test